# iOS Build settings Other Linker Flags

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project which is written in swift and i was trying to integrate GoogleSignIn in my project when the program kept crashing saying:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Then I googled the problem and found a solution to add -ObjC Other Linker Flag to my build settings.

So my question is what does this step does and how did it fix the problem.
Can anyone please explain what is Other Linker Flag and what it does?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your explanations about the "Other Linker Flag" and why fix the problem like this see :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html

> This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes.

Comment: When will we need to set "Other Linker Flag" since the linker should be smart enough to load every object it needs?